# MVC 5 Razor complete URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to assign to a javascript variable the full path of a .js file, so I thought I can use the tilde notation

```
<script>
    var lib = "~/Scripts/xlsx.core.min.js";
</script>
```

But this isn't translated as it would in `<script src="~/Scripts/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>`

Why is that? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: please check the update to an explanation

Comment: Where you are using `a` variable?

Comment: is this in an external js file load by angular or in the CSHTML file? In cshtml, it will be processed by the server (razor engine) so be correctly rendered as `a="/miApps..."` - this will not have any impact on the client-side / angular. If it is a .js or .html file the file will not be processed by MVC and razor, and so will be rendered by the server as is - `a = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts...")'`, and so error.

Comment: @Rhumborl you're right! I was doing that on a loaded js file! What a stupid! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are defining the variable in CSHTML file then use [`Url.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

```
<script>
   var lib = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/xlsx.core.min.js")';
</script>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. It just returns the same path without the `~` character.